# Apollo hooks useQuery and useMutation under the same component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I just recently started to learn GraphQL and React-Apollo and I'm wondering what's the recommended approach of using `useQuery` and `useMutation` hooks if I need them inside the same component.
Since both hooks return `{data, loading, error}` object the names are conflicting. Should I just assign unique names to the properties while destructuring or is it better to move the logic to separate container components?

Comment: IMHO it depends on the programming style and the specific situation. There is no definite answer here

Comment: THis is quite opinion based but here are some things to consider: 1. You seldomly use the data property of the mutation 2. often, your applciation works with the return value of the mutation function (`then`/`catch`) 3. you don't have to destructure, `xyzMutation.error` is fine. I think the really nice thing about hooks is that it is easy and convinient to use multiple at once (thin about `useState`).

Comment: For anyone who is wondering about the programmatic implications on this question:
it is totally valid to use multiple queries/mutations at the same time. To handle the variable naming you can just rename them, like `const { data: userData } = useQuery()`